# Will SQL 2008 Express still have a 10Gb limit if I use it to open a 2005 MDF file?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following situation: I have a production site running on SQL 2005 Express (only because it's free), and it's a reasonably big DB, and i'm always incredibly close to the 4 Gb limit. Every now and then I actually hit it and it's a big mess.

Now that SQL 2008 Express has 10Gb as a limit, I'm going to migrate.

The question is, if I just install SQL 2008, and attach the MDF file from 2005, will I have the 10 Gb limit? Or do I have to create a new Database from 2008, and then import the data?

If the latter, how do you recommend to do this import, what's the fastest and simplest way?

Thank you very much!
Daniel

Comment: Only R2 has the 10GB limit. Note that once migrated, there is no way back, the database is upgraded and you cannot attach it anymore to a SQL 2005 instance.

Comment: Good point about R2, thanks! I just double checked I downloaded the right version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Note that the 2005 database will autoamtically be updated. It is NOT and NEVER WAS a limit in the MDF file - the files are the same as for a "real" server. The limit was always in the software.

Comment: Awesome, just wanted to make sure before wasting a lot of hours finding out the hard way. Thank you!